I want to displaying a button on custome pannel while creating VS Code extension
I am creating my first ever extension.
What I am trying to do is, I am adding an icon on activitybar and I want to see a button one side panel when clicking on icon.
Problem: I am not seeing button on the side panel.
package.json
{
  "name": "myapi",
  "displayName": "myapi",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.92.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:myView"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "myExtension",
          "title": "My Extension",
          "icon": "resources/icon.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "myExtension": [
        {
          "id": "myView",
          "name": "My View"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.92.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.7",
    "@types/node": "20.x",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "@vscode/test-cli": "^0.0.9",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.4.0"
  }
}

extension.ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const myViewProvider = new MyViewProvider(context.extensionUri);

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(MyViewProvider.viewType, myViewProvider)
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.showPanel', () => {
            myViewProvider.showPanel();
        })
    );
}

class MyViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
    public static readonly viewType = 'myExtension.myView';
    private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;

    constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

    public resolveWebviewView(webviewView: vscode.WebviewView) {
        this._view = webviewView;

        webviewView.webview.options = {
            enableScripts: true,
        };

        webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);
    }

    public showPanel() {
        if (this._view) {
            this._view.show?.(true);
        }
    }

    private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview): string {
        return `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>My View</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <button onclick="alert('Button clicked!')">Click Me!</button>
            </body>
            </html>`;
    }
}

export function deactivate() {}




the image says there is no provider registered, get the WebviewView example running and determine the difference

@rioV8 you can see my package.json and extension.ts. I am not sure why it is showing provider not registered

If someone could share a example code for dispalying a button on side panel, that will also be helpful.


If your contributes.views type is default value: tree, please checkout contributes.viewsWelcome

If your contributes.views type is webview, you can controll it totally


In your case, contributes.views type is default value: tree, so you can't add button with webview, just checkout welcome-view-content-sample
